# How to remove account button and replace with simple account|login links

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, rwd-theme

I am using my own custom version of the RWD theme and want to remove the account button with the icon next to it and replace it with two simple account|login links that go to the account login/signup page.

Can anyone tell me how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>


        <reference name="top.links">

            <!-- Remove cart, checkout and wishlist top links -->
            <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
            <remove name="wishlist_link" />

            <!-- Remove my account top links -->
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/></action>

        </reference>

    </default>

        <!-- getting rid of login logout links in top .links -->
        <customer_logged_in>
            <reference name="top.links">
                <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
            </reference>
        </customer_logged_in>
        <customer_logged_out>
            <reference name="top.links">
                <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
            </reference>
        </customer_logged_out>


</layout>
```

In your phtml use this

```
<ul>
                        <li>
                        <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
                        <?php
                        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
                        $cusname = $customer->getFirstname().' '.$customer->getLastname();
                        $name = substr($cusname,0,18)."..";
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'); ?>"><?php echo "Hi "."$name"  ?> &nbsp;</a>
                            <ul  class="subaccount">
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account'); ?>">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>">Order</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('wishlist'); ?>">Wishlist</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('newsletter/manage'); ?>">Newsletter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('review/customer'); ?>">Review</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/logout'); ?>">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>">Login / Register</a>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: But how do I remove the current account button first?

Comment: You want to remove Account from top link?

Comment: I want to remove the account button with the icon that has a dropdown, and just replace it with two simple links (account|login) that go to the account page.

Comment: Your answer just edited the items in the dropdown. I want to delete the account button all together. And replace it with something else

Comment: Can you please share your url or Update Screen shot

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/171478031/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-26%20at%2016.45.24.png

I want to delete everything above the search, and replace it with two simple links that say account and login

Comment: Check my updated question remove unwanted link

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/171478031/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-26%20at%2017.12.03.png

That just removed some of the links under the account button. I want to delete the account button

Comment: that i con is css share your link i will tell you otherwise inspect element and check

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/171478031/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-26%20at%2017.16.33.png

if you look here it isnt just an icon there is a whole div that needs removing that contains both the icon and the dropdown

Comment: check account-cart-wrapper have background image you remove that

Comment: I know how to remove the image, but i don't want to just remove the image. I want to remove the whole of account-cart-wrapper

Comment: then goto that phtml and command it

Comment: I thought I would be able to simply remove it in local.xml

Comment: if you want to remove div then you should edit that particular phtml. If you want to remove particular link in top link then you edit local.xml